# Getting Friend list data with less read in Firestore

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

My project is in Ionic3, Angular2 and Firestore.
As Firestore costing depends on the number of reads I have the following concern.

I have the following structure for users.

```
User(collection)
    ->User ID(Doc)   -> Name:
                     -> Photo URL:
                     -> Friend (collection)
                            ->Friend ID (Doc) -> statue: Active
                            ->Friend ID (Doc) -> statue: Inactive
    ->User ID(Doc)  -> ...
```

Following this structure, if I want to show my friend list...

1. I will query the `Friend` collection for all active friends. (This is one read)
2. I have to loop through (read) all the IDs to get their `Name` and `Photo URL`.

So If a user has 200 friends. It will cost me 200 reads just to display the data.
Is there any better approach?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the exact same issue and I'm not sure how to create a good structure.

Comment: I am using the above structure. Did not get any better idea. :(

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use [database denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization): you duplicate the information you need (e.g. name and photoURL) in your Friend documents. This way, upon reads, you have all data for displaying what you want. For sure, there is a tradeoff. Upon friend updates, you have to either update all related documents or live with outdated information. However, it seems your use case has more reads than writes. As a consequence, it should not be a big issue to apply denormalization.